# Nodejs - DNS.Lookup is Rejecting URLs with HTTP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, dns, lookup

I'm trying to build an Api in Nodejs that takes a URL and checks that it's a valid website.

Right now the dns.lookup rejects any invalid URLs (fake websites), and accepts any valid URLs as long as they don't start with HTTP:// or HTTPS:// . That's problematic because valid URLs are being rejected.

So this URL produces the "No Errors" message:

```
dns.lookup('www.google.ca', function onLookup(err, address, family) 
  if (err == null) {
    console.log ('No Errors: ' + err + ' - ' + address + ' - ' + family) 
  } else {
    console.log ('Errors: ' + err + ' -- ' + address + ' -- ' + family)
  }
});
```

And this URL with HTTPS produces the "Errors" message:

```
dns.lookup('https://www.google.ca/', function onLookup(err, address, family) 
  if (err == null) {
    console.log ('No Errors: ' + err + ' - ' + address + ' - ' + family) 
  } else {
    console.log ('Errors: ' + err + ' -- ' + address + ' -- ' + family)
  }
});
```

The console.log output:

*Errors: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://www.google.ca/ -- undefined -- undefined*

Is there a way to configure the dns.lookup to accept URLs that start with HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: The docs say `dns.lookup()` takes a host name as the first param. https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback  `http` and `https` are protocols. would you be able to pull out those parts before you pass them in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dns.lookup` takes a hostname. Protocols are not part of a hostname, so they shouldn't be passed in. Just remove the http/https from the URL via regex, before passing it to the `dns.lookup` function:

```js
const url1 = 'https://google.ca';
const url2 = 'google.com';

const REPLACE_REGEX = /^https?:\/\//i

const res1 = url1.replace(REPLACE_REGEX, '');
const res2 = url2.replace(REPLACE_REGEX, '');

console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);

// dns.lookup(res1...);
```

Comment: That works! 
I'd been thinking of that earlier, but wasn't sure how to do it. I was also worried about adding the HTTP back in after the dns.lookup but I've realized that's not necessary.